# Javascript data available event

Tags: javascript, events

I am not expert at JavaScript/jQuery. so here I am .

I am calling a javascript function that takes some time to proecess. Is there any way to track the event when my data is available in success method. My code below.

```
function doWave() {
    window.plugins.AudioFxDemo.doConvert('http://c0458222.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/RC1_2.2_Conversation_line7.mp3',
        function(data) {
            // success
            alert(data);
        }, function(error) {
            alert(error);
        });
}
```

I am getting data but it takes some time. So how I can know when the data is available.

-Arefin

Comment: what is `window.plugins.AudioFxDemo.doConvert`?

Comment: The data is available when the success method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear to me what you're trying to do. The usual behavior of callback-based APIs is that the success method *gets called when data is available*. So just put in your handling code there. I suppose you could fire an [extra event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20trigger%20event) and process the data in another callback, but whether this makes sense or not depends on what you're trying to obtain.

Please also post more details about your programming environment (frameworks, targeted clients, tools etc.) so we can give you better advice. :)

---

## Update:

If you're trying to call the `doWave` function periodically, you can try this:

```
function doWave() {
    window.plugins.AudioFxDemo.doConvert('[url]',
        function(data) {
            // process data, display etc.
            // [...]

            // queue doWave for immediate execution
            setTimeout(doWave, 0);
        }, function(error) {
            alert(error);
        });
}
```

This way, everytime `doWave` is executed, another execution is queued, immediately after the current success function is done executing.

[Here's a nice article](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) about timer functions, if you want to learn more.

I'm still not sure that this is what you're looking for, please comment/update the question if it isn't.

Comment: thank you, basically this is a phonegap plugin for Android platform. And I call the doWave() function and gets data, but as the function actually calls a Java class to perform the main task (audio to waveform ), it takes some time and it is very practical. So I need to know when data is available in success method because after that I will call again dowave() function. Please give me a smart suggestion.

Comment: I still don't fully understand what you're trying to do, and I guess I'm not the only one. I have an idea, I'll edit my post and write it down, but you should edit your question as well and try to explain better what you're trying to do. "data available" to me means that the data is present in the callback function, and it is. Probably you mean something different by that.

Comment: sorry, let me give some times to understand the actual problem, then I will knock here.